# Find and install ember-cli latest LTS version using npm

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-cli

The [builds page of ember-cli](http://emberjs.com/builds/) lists

> The latest LTS release is 2.4.5, made on April 11th, 2016

But when I try `npm install -g ember-cli@2.4.5`, I receive an error `version not found: ember-cli@2.4.5`.

Also, I was unable to find `v2.4.5` on [Github releases](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases). The last `2.4.x` version is `2.4.3`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: That's the build page of ember not ember-cli, the last lts release for ember-cli is 2.4.3

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem lies in looking at the wrong site and trying to install a version that does not exist.

Comment: Thanks @kitler. I thought all cli, ember and ember date would have the same version

Comment: " and PATCH releases may include bug or security fixes." bug fixes and security fixes don't always apply to all 3 libs ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ember-cli and ember have different versions. Ember-cli 2.4.5 does not exist indeed, <strike>ember-cli does not even have a LTS version.</strike> However ember 2.4.5 does exist, see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tags).

Just use the latest ember-cli and change the ember version to LTS. The website you mentioned is talking about ember itself, not ember-cli. For ember-cli check http://ember-cli.com/.

<strike>PS: you might also notice that there is no LTS version of ember-data.</strike>

Comment: How and when do you "change the ember version to LTS"?  Does this step happen before or after `ember init` in the latest ember-cli release notes?